# Dimensions of containerNode inside dojox dialog widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to get the dimensions of my containerNode which is a member of my dojox dialog widget, when the widget's showing animation ends.

```
this.dialog = new dojox.widget.Dialog( { sizeToViewport: true });
var dialogContainer = this.dialog.containerNode;
```

Which function or property should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of possible sollutions

```
dojo.connect(mydialog, "show", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){

        var position = dojo.position(dialogContainer);
        var dimensions = {
            width: position.w,
            height: position.h
         }

        alert(position.h);
    },mydialog.duration + 1500);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `dojo V1.7` you could use [dojo.position](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/position.html).

With the given example:

```
    var position = dojo.position(dialogContainer);
    var dimensions = {
       width: position.w,
       height: position.h
    }
```

This call requires `dojo/dom-geometry`.

Let me know if it worked pls..

Comment: Sadly I am using dojo 1.6. But I think example would not work. My dialog has the sizeToWieport option set to true, which means that it will expand almost to the end of the screen. I need to find the dimensions when the expanding animation is over so I can set the contents of the dialog to the same size.

Comment: use `dojo.coords(dialogContainer);` in this case. But i don't know if this requires anything, but according to the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/coords.html) i guess not :)

Comment: The function returns some values but the are not the right values since they are called before the dialog is finished expanding. On which event or property should I use this function to get the right values.

Comment: i think it should be called after `startup` or `toggle`, whatever you use to expand it.. maybe a fiddle would fasten this up ;)

Comment: If I call it after the dialog.startup() event nothing changes!

Comment: I have all the things I need i just need to have the dialog dimensions when the expanding stops.

Comment: if i get this rigth, you want to get set the dimensions of the dialog depending on the dimensions of its Container Node (so that it has, like, "maxi"-size). Pleass provide a fiddle, so that i can have a more detailed look..

Comment: I start a dialog which is "maxi"-size. :) Now I need the dialogContainer dimensions which is expanded with the dialog so I can set the dimension of all the other content I want to put in the dialogContainer.

Comment: what do you use to toggle it (u spoke of some kind of animation)?

Comment: With the animation I was meaning the expanding.

Comment: Alrigth, I think this leads to nothing like that. Try `var position = this.dialog.get('dimensions')` (or was it without 's'?) and if that doesn't work, please provide a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the issue or i guess i can not help you :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Pdycb/21/ at this example I set the dialog size and the alert function gives me the correct size. But when I change the size to sizeToViewport: true like here http://jsfiddle.net/Pdycb/22/ the alert button doesn't give me right values!

The dialog doesn't get shown it this examples but that is not the case!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 2nd attempt now. As experimenting a little bit, didn't lead to a solution. How about a nasty little workaround?

Researching on the `sizeToViewPort`-option of the `dojox.widget.dialog` i found out, that by default there is a `padding` of `35px` to the `ViewPort`. So if you know the size of the `viewport`, you could get the dimensions of the dialog by substracting the padding from it..

So maybe this helps:

```
    function getNewDialog(the_padding) {
        if (!the_padding || isNaN(the_padding)) {
            the_padding = 35;
        }
        var dialog = new dojox.widget.Dialog({
            sizeToViewport: true,
            padding: the_padding + 'px' //nasty string conversion
        });

        return dialog;
    }

    function getViewPortSize() {
        var viewPortWidth;
        var viewPortHeight;
        // mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7
        if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
            viewPortWidth = window.innerWidth;
            viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight;
        }
        // IE6 in standards compliant mode
        else if (typeof document.documentElement !== 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !== 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth !== 0) {
            viewPortWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            viewPortHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        // older versions of IE fallback
        else {
            viewPortWidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
            viewPortHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
        }

        return {
            width: viewPortWidth,
            heigth: viewPortHeight
        };
    }

    function getDialogSize(the_padding) {
        if (!the_padding) {
            the_padding = 35;
        }

        var vp_size = getViewPortSize();

        return {
            width: vp_size.width - the_padding,
            heigth: vp_size.heigth - the_padding
        };
    }

    var costumPadding = 35; // this is also the default value of dojox.widget.dialog ...
    var dialog = getNewDialog(costumPadding);
    var dialogSize = getDialogSize(costumPadding);
```

Hope I didn't miss anything.